# Java Spring error: not-null property references a null or transient value, in many to one relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have three entities: FamilyMember, Comment and PersonalPage. A family member can post many comments, and a single comment belongs to one family member, so it is a many-to-one relationship. In addition, a personal page can have many comments, but a single comment belongs to one personal page. So it is a many-to-one relationship also.
I coded all this database structure in Java Spring, to create an API. When I try to perform a post to save a comment, it shows this error:

> not-null property references a null or transient value : com.coronahelp.entity.Comment.familyMember

I searched for a solution, but I didn't find any answer similar to my problem.
Here is the code for the classes involved (bear in mind that Family member extends from Person). The Id for a Family member is a string.

```
package com.coronahelp.entity;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Person {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String secondSurname;


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        if(id.trim().length() > 0)
        {
            this.id = id;
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        if(name.trim().length() > 0)
        {
            this.name= name;
        }
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        if(surname.trim().length() > 0)
        {
            this.surname= surname;
        }
    }

    public String getSecondSurname() {
        return secondSurname;
    }

    public void setSecondSurname(String secondSurname) {
        if(secondSurname.trim().length() > 0)
        {
            this.secondSurname = secondSurname;
        }
    }
}
```

```
package com.coronahelp.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
public class FamilyMember extends Person{
    public FamilyMember()
    {
        super();
    }
    public FamilyMember(String id, String name, String surname, String secondSurname) {
        super(id, name, surname, secondSurname);
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="familyMember")
    private Set<Comment> comment;
}
```

```
package com.coronahelp.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
public class PersonalPage {
    public PersonalPage()
    {
        this.public = false;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="personalPage")
    private Set<Comment> comment;

    private String illnessStory;
    public boolean public;

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public String getIllnessStory()
    {
        return illnessStory;
    }

    public void setillnessStory (String illnessStory)
    {
        if(illnessStory.trim().length() > 0)
        {
            this.illnessStory = illnessStory;
        }
    }

    public void setPublic(boolean public)
    {
        this.public = public;
    }

    public boolean getPublic()
    {
        return public;
    }
}
```

```
package com.coronahelp.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
public class Comment {
    public Comment()
    {

    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="family_member_id", nullable = false)
    private FamilyMember familyMember;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="personal_page", nullable = false)
    private PersonalPage personalPage;    

    private Date date;
    private String text;

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public String getDate()
    {
        return date.toString();
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public void setText(String text)
    {
        if(text.trim().length() > 0)
        {
            this.text = text;
        }
    }

    public String getText()
    {
        return text;
    }

}
```

Here is the code for the repository, service and controller.

```
package com.coronahelp.repository;

import com.coronahelp.entity.Comment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface CommentRepository extends JpaRepository<Comment, Integer> {
}
```

```
package com.coronahelp.service;

import com.coronahelp.entity.Comment;
import com.coronahelp.repository.CommentRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class CommentService {
    @Autowired
    private CommentRepository repository;

    public Comment saveComment(Comment comment)
    {
        return repository.save(comment);
    }

//other CRUD operations
}
```

```
package com.coronahelp.controllers;

import com.coronahelp.entity.Comment;
import com.coronahelp.service.CommentService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class CommentController {
    @Autowired
    private CommentService service;

    @PostMapping("/saveComment")
    public Comment saveComment(@RequestBody Comment comment)
    {
        return service.saveComment(comment);
    }

    //other CRUD operations
}
```

Finally, this is my post I did with Postman, please check if it is correct. Remember that I'm trying to save a comment:
http://localhost:8787/saveComment

```
{
    "familyMember": {
        "id": "2"
    },
    "personalPage" : {
        "id": 1
    },
    "date": "2021-05-16",
    "text": "my comment"
}
```

Please, help me with this problem. If the solution is obvious, don't be hard on me. I'm just starting to learn Spring. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want FamilyMember to be created when you save new Comments or FamilyMember should already exist when adding new Comments?

Comment: A FamilyMember should already exist. In the database, the column family_member_id of the comment table, should be the foreign key.

Comment: from the exception comment.familyMember is either null or it does not exist yet in the database. could you put a breakpoint on `return repository.save(comment);`, run your postman, and on breakpoint reached see which one is the case?

Comment: I placed a breakpoint on that line. It shows both familyMember and personalPage as null. What is rare, is that I do have  in the database a family member with Id: 2 and a personal page with id: 1. It seems that it is failing finding the requested family member and personal page.

Comment: this might mean your json deserialization does not create members familyMember and personalPage in the received Comment in your @PostMapping

Comment: Ok, I understand your point, Is there a way to check how Spring is deserializing this JSON? In most of the API tutorials, the function to save an object (marked with @PostMapping) receives a class object, so the deserialization is done somewhere.